# how to find an element with the parameter as selected and output it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie with javascript and meet a problem like this.

For example . there is a variable with a list like this

```
{
    name: 'x',
    attack: 50,
    speed: 100,
    hitpoint: 100,
},
{
    name: 'y',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 80,
    hitpoint: 180,
}
```

Find an variable with an attack = 150 and return it in the function "findAMonsterByAttack"
If there is no matching variable in the list of variable, the "findAMonsterByAttack" function returns null.

Here is my code :

```
function findAMonsterByAttack(monsters) {
var monsters = [
{
    name: 'x',
    attack: 50,
    speed: 100,
    hitpoint: 100,
},
{
    name: 'y',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 80,
    hitpoint: 180,
},
// ...
];
var isfree = monsters.every(function(course, index) {
return course.attack ===150;
});
```

My idea is using the code every to check course and index, then return if the attach = 150. But I failed.
Could you please help me with this case ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If `monsters` is an array, you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return another array with of only the `monsters` with a matching criteria.

eg `attack === 150`.

Note that there could be multiple matches, so this would return an array with *all of the `monsters`* that match, (or an empty array if no `monsters` match).

```js
const monsters = [{
    name: 'x',
    attack: 50,
    speed: 100,
    hitpoint: 100,
  },
  {
    name: 'y',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 80,
    hitpoint: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'z',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 90,
    hitpoint: 150,
  }
]

const a150 = monsters.filter(m => m.attack === 150)

console.log(a150)
```

If you only care about one `monster`, you could also use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). But this would return the *first `monster`* found and `undefined` if no matches are found.

```js
const monsters = [{
    name: 'x',
    attack: 50,
    speed: 100,
    hitpoint: 100,
  },
  {
    name: 'y',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 80,
    hitpoint: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'z',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 90,
    hitpoint: 150,
  }
]

const a150 = monsters.find(m => m.attack === 150)

console.log(a150)
```

Note: [array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) tests whether *all `monsters`* meet the criteria and returns a `Boolean` value. In your example this will return `false` because all `monsters` *do not* have an attack value of 150.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function findAMonsterByAttack() {
var monsters = [
{
    name: 'x',
    attack: 50,
    speed: 100,
    hitpoint: 100,
},
{
    name: 'y',
    attack: 150,
    speed: 80,
    hitpoint: 180,
}
// ...
];

for ( m of monsters ) {
  if ( m.attack == 150 )
    return m
}
return "Monster with attack 150 not found"
}

console.log(findAMonsterByAttack())
```